# How can I use JPA to search for a substring on a field?

Tags: java, jpa

My application uses JPA to access the backend database.

I have a Java class mapped to a table. The class has a string field (called status) that consists of a series of "0"s and "1"s. I need to select a few records based on the field's second character. Here is what I can do without using JPA (I am using MS SQLServer).

```
SELECT * FROM Machines where SUBSTRING(status, 2, 1) = '1'
```

How can I do it using JPA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a SUBSTRING function in JPA:

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf

**4.6.17.2.1 "String functions"**

> (...)
>
> SUBSTRING(string_primary, simple_arithmetic_expression [, simple_arithmetic_expression])
>
> (...)
>
> The second and third arguments of the SUBSTRING function denote the starting position and
>   length of the substring to be returned. These arguments are integers.
>   The third argument is optional. If it is not specified, the substring
>   from the start position to the end of the string is returned. The
>   first position of a string is denoted by 1. The SUBSTRING function
>   returns a string.

Comment: Piotr, I appreciate your input very much. Best.

Answer (score 5):

JPQL has the `SUBSTRING(..)` function as well: [see here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_query_functions). So it will be the same as in the native query.

When JPA doesn't support some function that you need, you can make a native query and map the result to a pojo.

Comment: Bozho, I checked out the document and tried the substring function and everything works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

JPQL has a substring function which can be used to trim entities.  Make sure you use entity names in your query and also note that the **substring function is not zero indexed**.

```
SELECT * FROM Machines m where SUBSTRING(m.status, 2, 1) = '1'
```