# "SUBSTR" with "CONCAT" in named query result in exception - Invalid parameter count for "SUBSTR"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have a name-query written in orm.xml file which is correctly linked with `persistence.xml` as:

```
select 
    distinct b.id
from
    BEntity b, AEntity a
where 
    b.id in (:ids) 
    and (a.someColumn = b.someColumn or (concat(substr(b.someColumn, 1, 8), 'XXX') 
                                          = a.someColumn) or a.someColumn = '**') 
    and (a.beneficiaryBIC=b.beneficiaryBIC or (concat(substr(b.beneficiaryBIC, 1, 8), 'XXX') 
                                             = a.beneficiaryBIC) or a.beneficiaryBIC = '**')
```

But when I am trying to execute this query I am getting error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid parameter count for "SUBSTR",
           expected count: "2..3"; SQL statement:
select distinct b0_.id as col_0_0_ from TABLE_NAME_B b0_ cross join TABLE_NAME_A a1_ where 
(b0_.id in ()) and (a1_.someColumn=b0_.someColumn or (substr(b0_.someColumn||1||8)||'XXX')
=a1_.someColumn or a1_.someColumn='**') and (a1_.beneficiaryBIC=b0_.beneficiaryBIC or 
(substr(b0_.beneficiaryBIC||1||8)||'XXX')=a1_.beneficiaryBIC or a1_.beneficiaryBIC='**')
```

As I can see the `substr(b0_.someColumn, 1, 8)` is changed to `substr(b0_.someColumn||1||8)` which is causing this parameter count issue but why `,` is replaced with `||` here?

Comment: There is no "SUBSTR" function in JPQL. A simple look at the JPA spec tells you that. There is `SUBSTRING`

Comment: repalce `SUBSTR` by `SUBSTRING`

Comment: @mjsoft: but the `SUBSTR` was working before without any error until I added the `CONCAT`.

Comment: no substr is not in `jpql` it is in `hql`  you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115217/how-can-i-use-jpa-to-search-for-a-substring-on-a-field)

Comment: @mjsoft: ok. it works well with `SUBSTRING`. but why the `,` is being replaced to `||`? And why the exception says `Invalid parameter count for "SUBSTR"`? You can add an answer with explanation.